# Resources$NotFoundException: on Splash Background Samsung 8.0.0 devices only

Tags: android

Crash Happening only on Samsung 8.0.0 devices, I am not using any vector drawable.

Theme Slash is

```
<style name="Theme_Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/bar_style</item>
    <item tools:targetApi = "23" name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashbackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

</style>

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ui.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example:drawable/splashbackground with resource ID #0x7f08088c
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your **splashbackground** image file. Most probably its in *drawable-hdpi* or *mdpi* or similar folder, not in **drawable** folder.

Moving it to **drawable** folder should fix the issue

Comment: my splashbackground.xml is using a splash.webp which is in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, how this fix issue to move in drawable folder can you provide some ref or reason.

Comment: Phones which are mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi resolution, wont crash, because they can get the image from their **respective drawable directories**.
Phones of other resolutions find the image in the default **drawable** directory, if the image is not there, it will crash. 
Please add one copy of the image in res/drawable/ also. **not in any resolution specific drawables